# React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. Using useMediaQuery responsive JS media query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use responsive javascript media queries using `useMediaQuery` however I can't get it to work, I get: -

Error message:
`"useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

Playground
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5vseqr?file=media-query.ts

I think it's erroring on line 4 of `media-query.ts`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useMediaQuery = (query: string) => {
    const [match, setMatch] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const updateMatch = () => setMatch(window.matchMedia(query).matches)

        updateMatch()
        window.matchMedia(query).addEventListener('change', updateMatch)

        return () => {
            window.matchMedia(query).removeEventListener('change', updateMatch)
        }
    }, [query])

    return match
}

export default useMediaQuery
```

Comment: The problem is likely were your using `useMediaQuery`. Are you calling it from inside a functional react component?

Comment: Just checked snippet, and indeed your calling this outside a React functional component like the error says.

Comment: @Keith What would I need to change in order to get this working? Sorry, im just at a loss with this, im new to react world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done here is writing a custom hook(useMediaQuery). You've done that properly so no issues there. Above code snipped is fine.

The problem is in the index.tsx file when you try to use the above custom hook that you've written. As the error suggests your custom hook is called outside the react component there in line 7 of index.tsx.

You have to move the useMediaQuery call inside the App component. Also currently your App component is a class component which you have to convert to a functional component to use hooks inside it.

here's the adjusted code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-m6rwpd?file=index.tsx

Comment: Thank you! I was looking all along in the wrong file. Totally see the problem now, thank you!